# How to use data_structure_typed library in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[This is great library to make algorithm visualizer project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/data-structure-typed)

But this docs of this library is very difficult to understand [docs](https://data-structure-typed-docs.vercel.app/classes/DoublyLinkedList.html)

has anyone used this library before?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/data-structure-typed/dist/umd/data-structure-typed.js'></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx" const {Heap} = dataStructureTyped;
    const {
      BinaryTree, Graph, Queue, Stack, PriorityQueue, BST, Trie, DoublyLinkedList,
      AVLTree, MinHeap, SinglyLinkedList, DirectedGraph, TreeMultimap,
      DirectedVertex, AVLTreeNode
    } = dataStructureTyped;></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I pasted above code in index.html as mentioned in docs

```
import {
    BinaryTree, IGraph, Queue, Stack, PriorityQueue, BST, Trie, DoublyLinkedList,
    AVLTree, MinHeap, SinglyLinkedList, DirectedGraph, TreeMultimap,
    DirectedVertex, AVLTreeNode
  } from 'data-structure-typed';

  export interface IGraph<V, E, VO, EO> {
    createVertex(key: VertexKey, value?: V): VO;
  
    createEdge(srcOrV1: VertexKey, destOrV2: VertexKey, weight?: number, value?: E): EO;
  }
```

done this in Graph.jsx file
I literally don't know how to utlize this library. can someone show how to use this library by making small project on this?